# AppleのチュートリアルでValue of type 'Color' has no member 'accessibleFontColor'とエラーが出る

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, swiftui

AppleのiOS dev tutorialsで、会議の情報を表示するレッスンでエラーが出ました。
改善策を教えてください、よろしくお願いします。

[Creating a CardView — iOS App Dev Tutorials | Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/creating-a-cardview)

---

**エラー**

```
Value of type 'Color' has no member 'accessibleFontColor'
```

**参照する会議の情報**

```
import SwiftUI

struct DailyScrum {
    var title: String
    var attendees: [String]
    var lengthInMinutes: Int
    var color: Color
}

extension DailyScrum {
    static var data: [DailyScrum] {
        [
            DailyScrum(title: "Design", attendees: ["Cathy", "Daisy", "Simon", "Jonathan"], lengthInMinutes: 10, color: Color("Design")),
            DailyScrum(title: "App Dev", attendees: ["Katie", "Gray", "Euna", "Luis", "Darla"], lengthInMinutes: 5, color: Color("App Dev")),
            DailyScrum(title: "Web Dev", attendees: ["Chella", "Chris", "Christina", "Eden", "Karla", "Lindsey", "Aga", "Chad", "Jenn", "Sarah"], lengthInMinutes: 1, color: Color("Web Dev"))
        ]
    }
}
```

**カードのUI**

```
import SwiftUI

struct CardView: View {
    let scrum: DailyScrum
    var body: some View {
        VStack (alignment: .leading){
            Text(scrum.title)
                .font(.headline)
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Label("\(scrum.attendees.count)", systemImage: "person.3")
                Spacer()
                Label("\(scrum.lengthInMinutes)", systemImage: "clock")
                    .padding(.trailing, 20)
            }
            .font(.caption)
        }
        .padding()
        .foregroundColor(scrum.color.accessibleFontColor)
    }
}

struct CardView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var scrum = DailyScrum.data[0]
    static var previews: some View {
        CardView(scrum: scrum)
            .background(scrum.color)
            .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 400, height: 60))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

おそらくゼロから自分でプロジェクトを作っていないでしょうか。

チュートリアルと読むと

> accessibleFontColor is a property defined in the starting project. It returns either black or white, depending on how light or dark the scrum color is.

とあります。

`the starting project` が何を指すのかここだけ読むと意味不明ですが、
チュートリアルの冒頭に

> Download the starter project and follow along with this tutorial, or open the finished project and explore the code on your own.

とあり

`Project files`と下向き矢印があるところからプロジェクトをダウンロードできます。

ダウンロードが終わって開いてみると

`Complete` と `StartingPoint` というフォルダがあります。

この`StartingPoint`にあるプロジェクトに結構すでにコードが書かれています。
このすでに書かれたコードに`'accessibleFontColor'`の定義がありました。

ですので、このチュートリアルは、`StartingPoint`にあるプロジェクトからはじめて、それに手を加えていってください。

もし他にわからないことがチュートリアル途中で出た場合は、`Complete`が完成品のようですので、こちらと照らし合わせるとよいかと思います。